# C project with two examples, only one seems to compile, makefile issue

Tags: c, makefile

I'm working on an open source C project that has two example files to run the library, one called example.c, and one called test.c.

The Makefile consists of the following:

```
test:       test.c src/term.c
            $(CC) $^ -o $@

example:    example.c src/term.c
            $(CC) -std=c99 $^ -o $@

.PHONY:     test example
```

However, when I run make and then do ./test, test runs, but when I do ./example, it doesn't.  Any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you run `make example`?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you try to run `example`, and what actually happens? Do you get a different result when you build "by hand" (that is, without Make)? Is `example.c` simple enough to post? **EDIT:** I think @AlexReynolds hit it.

Comment: When you run make only `test` executable binary is created. Try running `make example`. And post the log you are getting

Comment: Guys if you post a bit of that stuff w/slightly more explanation of why make only does the test executable, I'll upvote/accept, since it worked.

Comment: Ask yourself this: When running `make` all by its lonesome, whats is the *first* direct target that make encounters when processing your multi-target Makefile from top to bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just type `make` the first target is being executed, in your case its test. So you will get only `test` executable. But if you type `make example` then `example` target is executed and you will get `example` binary. I think you need fresh up with Makefile rules.You can refer [this](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.in/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html) for basic concepts or [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for in depth understanding

Comment: The behavior the OP is expecting can probably be obtained by adding `all: test example` at the top of the Makefile. Also, the last line should be `.PHONY: all` ...it should not include `test` or `example` since those targets correspond to actual files.